# Gif de carregar enquanto site carrega!

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um site (MVC), onde nele há uma opção do usuário selecionar um arquivo Excel, e todos os dados da tabela são enviados para o banco de dados e só depois aparece uma aviso de sucesso ou falha ao gravar os dados.

Esta tarefa leva um certo tempo e durante este tempo o site fica carregando. Isso pode levar o usuário a pensar que o site travou, por isso durante este tempo pensei em colocar um gif de carregamento e quando aparecesse o aviso de sucesso ou falha o gif desapareceria.

Como faço isso? Encontrei algumas coisas na internet como coloca-los em uma div e usar as funções hide e show, mas nada como o efeito esperado.

Pensei também ao invés de mostrar o aviso ele ser redirecionado para outra tela quando terminasse, pensando que assim seria mais fácil imprimir este efeito, porém mais uma vez sem sucesso. Gostaria de alguma sugestão para que eu pudesse finalizar este trabalho do técnico com exito.

Comment: da uma olhada nesse [Loading](https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/#quick-demo) , eu uso em algumas aplicações e funciona bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <img id="loading" src="../../Content/progress.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display: none;" />
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#loading').hide();

            $('#btnPostarExcel').click(
                function() {

                    $('#loading').show();

                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```